# Pagination With Special Recent Posts Plugin (WordPress)

Tags: pagination, wordpress

I am using the 'Special Recent Posts' plug-in in WordPress. It is being used to show header images and excerpts for articles, which you then click through to the full article.

You can set parameters on that plug-in to tell how many recent articles you would like show. Basically what I want to do is show the first five articles on the main page and then have the overflow go to new pages (like an 'older posts' type thing where there would be five posts per page).

Can anyone help me get pointed in the right direction? Every time I Google this question it doesn't quite understand...Thanks.

---

EDIT:

I saw the first answer and while it is moving in the right direction, it doesn't automatically generate the new pages like I would like. I want to have the overflow of special recent posts generate a new 'previous' page automatically. I understand that I could manually do this but the blog I am working on will be getting updated every day so it would be very time consuming to constantly create new pages as I go along. Can somebody point me in the right direction?

---

EDIT:
Here is the full code I have on my index.php:

`<?php get_header(); ?>`

`<?php c2c_the_category_image($image_extensions='png gif jpg', $image_dir='/wp-content/images/', $use_name_if_no_image=true, $start_from='begin', $limit=999); ?>`

`<?php echo do_shortcode("[srp srp_number_post_option='34' srp_thumbnail_option='yes' srp_widget_title_hide_option='yes' srp_post_date_option='no' srp_wdg_excerpt_length='50' srp_wdg_excerpt_length_mode='fullexcerpt']"); ?>`

`<?php get_sidebar(); ?>`

`<?php get_footer(); ?>`

Comment: I edited my answer to show an example based on your index.php code, please let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Did you get a chance to try the updated answer?

Comment: I am looking at it now, thanks, I'll get back to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The plugin has a parameter for this, from the documentation:

```
//Global Post Offset (to skip an arbitrary number of posts from the beginning)
srp_post_global_offset_option => numeric
```

So, on the second page, to skip 5 posts and then show the next 5, you would want something like this:

```
[srp srp_number_post_option='5' srp_post_global_offset_option='5']
```

**Documentation:** http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/special-recent-posts/installation/

EDIT: To answer your question about generating new pages, technically you would not. You would have one page that would show different posts, acting like it was a different page. You would probably need use a query string (URL parameter). But, you can't put direct PHP into a wordpress post, so you need to either modify a PHP file, or get a WordPress plugin like Shortcode Exec PHP, so you can take the page number parameter from the URL and put it into the shortcode for special recent posts.

**Example based on your index.php code:**

```
$offset = ($_GET['page'] * 5) - 5;
echo do_shortcode("[srp srp_number_post_option='34' srp_thumbnail_option='yes'
srp_widget_title_hide_option='yes' srp_post_date_option='no'
srp_wdg_excerpt_length='50' srp_wdg_excerpt_length_mode='fullexcerpt'
srp_post_global_offset_option='".$offset."']");
```

Make your *first* page use

```
index.php?page=1
```

And your "Next Page" link:

```
$next = $_GET['page'] + 1;
echo '<a href="index.php?page='.$next.'">Next Page</a>';
```

Comment: When you mean multiple pages, I'm assuming you're referring to having it go over 2 pages? I suppose my questions is, is there a way to have it automatically generate new pages when an overflow over 5 happens? I look at a site like mashable.com and they have like 2,110 pages of articles that you can scroll back through which I'm assuming are automatically generated as needed.

Comment: I'm gonna modify my answer above a little... You would probably need use a query string (URL parameter). If you were using PHP, your page would be news.php?page=1 and your code would be something like [srp srp_number_post_option='5' srp_post_global_offset_option='<?php $_GET['page'] * 5 ?>']  (the offset would be the page number times 5). But, you can't put direct PHP into a wordpress post, so you need to either modify a PHP file, or get a WordPress plugin like Shortcode Exec PHP

Comment: I've used Shortcode Exec PHP (but again am still a little new to this). Essentially I would be creating my own shortcode by incorporating the SRP shortcode within it. For example I would make a shortcode named something like "hello_world" that would contain: $offset = $_GET['page'] * 5;
echo do_shortcode("[srp srp_number_post_option='34' srp_thumbnail_option='yes'
srp_widget_title_hide_option='yes' srp_post_date_option='no'
srp_wdg_excerpt_length='50' srp_wdg_excerpt_length_mode='fullexcerpt'
srp_post_global_offset_option='".$offset."']"); and then run hello_world on the index page?

Comment: To clarify, I would experiment but I'm working on a site that's already live so I want to try to understand this fully before I start to add things in. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I based my example off the index.php example you gave. Just replace the line that has "do_shortcode" with the same line from my example (including the line that defines $offset). The only difference is I included the offset, so each page skips the appropriate number of posts. The code gets the offset by checking the page parameter in the URL and then multiplying it by 5 and subtracting 5. For example for page 3: 3 * 5 = 15, 15 - 5 = 10, so page 3 would skip the first 10 posts and show 11 through 15. You're not actually generating a new page just displaying different posts on the same page.

Comment: Ah, I get it! That's perfect. Thank you so much. The one last question I have (and thanks again for helping me through, I really appreciate it) is how to make the index.php become index.php?page=1. Do I literally have to change the file name or is there a way to have WordPress generate that itself?

Comment: Well when you link to it, you could link it that way. (See what I wrote above about the link increasing the page number). But if you wanted you could also add some code at the very top of the index.php to refresh the page with that parameter if it is not currently present. Something like this: if(!isset($_GET['page'])){header('Location: index.php?page=1');}

Comment: Ok I'll try that. The problem I was having was when I entered the code it was starting with the fifth post on the index.php page instead of starting from post number 1. I was assuming that was because an integer hadn't been set for the first page? Let me try this...

Comment: So make sure $offset = ($_GET['page'] * 5) - 5;   (the minus five should correct for that), so page 1, offset is 1*5 - 5 = 0 (skip 0 posts), page 2, offset is 2*5 - 5 = 5 (skip 5 posts), page 3 offset is 3 * 5 - 5 = 10 (skip 10 posts), etc..

Comment: Ah, what happened was the original code you wrote had the -5 in it so it was going back five posts initially. I just took that out. Again, thank you so much for walking me through this, I feel like I have a better understanding, not just of this function, but of ideas for later use. I appreciate the walkthrough.

Answer (score 0):

I never worked before the [special recent post plugin](http://wordpress.org/support/plugin/special-recent-posts). So i would like to give WordPress query post solution.

First, to get recent five post in home page (index.php) use below query parameter.

```
$query = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=5');
```

Second, to list older post in other page use below query parameter.

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => 5, 'offset' => 5 ) );
```

Above query will get posts from 6 and 5 post per page.To add pagination, add paging parameter.Refer [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

Comment: My question is that this works with WordPress when you're using a normal theme but I've editing my theme with the Special Recent Posts Plugin (basically to have a preview of each article on the main page). Where would I apply pagination within this? The 'post_per_page and offset parameters are coded within the plugin itself. I've added the code of my page above (with the plugin coding).

Answer (score 0):

Pagination is [now available](http://www.specialrecentposts.com) in the new Special Recent Posts PRO Edition version 3.0.0